# JQUERY Ajax When I Click A Href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am new to JavaScript, Jquery and Ajax. This is what I am trying to do:

When I click on Pro-Hashtagh, I want to display a word in Show-Id.

This Pro-Hashtagh HTML code:

```
<li>
    <a href="#" id="Pro-Hashtagh">Pro Hashtagh</a>
</li>
```

Show-Id HTML code:

```
<div class="body" id="Show-Id">
</div>
```

Ajax Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        var waiting = '<center><h3>Please Wait ...</h3></center>';

        $('#Pro-Hashtagh').click(function(){
            $("#Show-Id").html(waiting);
        });

    });

</script>
```

But when I click, nothing happens

Comment: Did you include jQuery?

Comment: And FYI: There is Zero Ajax code in your question.

Comment: Use event.preventDefault() prevent the default action

Comment: yes, <script src="plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: Your code works, so what is different with that you have and what is in the page? Are the lis dynamically loaded?

Comment: @ALFIANANANDAPUTRA - Please make sure check and confirm the path of the script. go the page sourec and click on the jquery.min.js see whether the script is loading or not

Comment: Nothing happens, the network tab in my inspect element does not show anything when I click Pro-Hashtag

Comment: So learn to debug:     `console.log("before");
$(function () { console.log("document ready");

        var waiting = '<center><h3>Please Wait ...</h3></center>';
       console.log("I found:", $('#Pro-Hashtagh').length)
        $('#Pro-Hashtagh').click(function(){ 
console.log("I am in the click", $("#Show-Id").length);
            $("#Show-Id").html(waiting);
        });

    });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created a fiddle with your code and everything seams to be fine.

https://jsfiddle.net/eh2xbxpe/

Of course you have to add Jquery to your project, that'S the only error I see.

Beside, you don't call any AJAX request in your code, you are just adding a please wait. If you are trying to reach an external ressources via AJAX, it is not the case here.

```js
    $(function () {

        var waiting = '<center><h3>Please Wait ...</h3></center>';

        $('#Pro-Hashtagh').click(function(){
            $("#Show-Id").html(waiting);
        });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
    <a href="#" id="Pro-Hashtagh">Pro Hashtagh</a>
</li>
<div class="body" id="Show-Id">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're working on a local environment.
Something happens when you click on the link but the page reloads way to fast for you to see anything. You need to update your onclick event so it prevent the link default behavior.

```
$('#Pro-Hashtagh').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#Show-Id").html(waiting);
});
```

Comment: A `#` is not going to reload the page, it will scroll the page.

Comment: @epascarello it will scroll to page if there is an `<anchor>` tag the code is fine.

Answer (score -2):

try

```
<a href="#" id="Pro-Hashtagh" onclick="check()">Pro Hashtagh</a>
```

and create check function in javascript

Comment: Its be a comment

Comment: @SudharsanS by mistake i wrote wrong .. please give me positive vote

Answer (score -3):

```
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="body" id="Show-Id">
</div>
<li>
    <a href="#" id="Pro-Hashtagh">Pro Hashtagh</a>
</li>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

       var waiting = '<center><h3>Please Wait> .     

 ..</h3></center>';

           $('#Pro-Hashtagh').click(function(){
           $("#Show-Id").html(waiting);
      });

  });

</script>
```

Comment: What you are trying to say from this post?

Comment: This code is working correctly for me . i think jquery.min.js file is not properly linked in ALFIAN ANANDA PUTRA code.